Software using just 2 cores on a 13700 on Windows 10 64, crashing and getting stuck
I've the weirdest problem I ever encountered in my time working with computers :-).
I have music production software which was working fine until suddenly the program mainly started using just 1 or 2 cores (core 8 and 10) on a 13700k. In task manager or resource monitor i see those cores going to 100% and whilst doing that, the software hangs, often leading to crashing. The strangest thing is that I can change affinity of the process, remove core 8 and 10 and that seems to fix the issue. I contacted support of the program and they have no clue. Other customers run the software fine without problems.
Other software, VR programs, or heavy-CPU programs have no issues at all and use all cores. There must be something messing with the software in Windows(?), I did a reinstall which made no difference.
The program didn't update (tried to update but didn't help), I've updated all drivers and BIOS to the latest version (Z790 chipset). Running on performance mode in energy settings. Checked CPU temps, they remain under 70C, CPU-load in taskmanager is just 5-7% while the program hangs.
Does anyone have any clue? I'm completely stuck for months now, thank you so much.
To add, I noted that the cores that are getting overloaded are P-Cores and are core 4 and 5 (8 and 10 hyperthreaded I assume). The strange thing is these cores run on 5400mhz, while other P cores run on 5300mhz. This is an ASUS screenshot, hwinfo64 shows the same:
Screenshot
Could that be the culprit here? What is causing this? When I disable these cores in the process affinity the software runs OK.

Try running with Windows in SAFE mode to see if there is a conflict with another app.

Yea, to echo Joep's comment: Please give us more information.

Hello, thanks for the help so far. The software is FL Studio. In my debugging I found another weird thing. The cores that are getting overloaded run at 5400 mhz, while all other cores are running 5300mhz. Why could that be? Could that be the reason Windows is overloading these cores causing the software to crash?

"Are core 8 and 10 not e-cores?" - You wll have to tell us which cores are p-cores and e-cores.  If core 8 and 10 are e-cores then that would explain the performance.

No, core 8 is p-core 4, core 10 is p-core 5. It's getting weirder by the day. When I have a project in the software that gets stuck, the CPU temperature gets higher (65 degrees C) and 8 and 10 are 100% load. When I then remove core 8 and 10 on affinity in the process list the load gets distributed to other cores (also e cores) and temperature goes down to 38 C. Software resumes normal operation.

@Slacker - My suggestion would be to stop setting the processor affinity for the application

As stated in my comments above I noticed that some cores run on 5400 MHz, according to some overclock forums this is factory default to use them as "main" P-cores. This seems to cause the issues. In my BIOS there is a setting "Sync all P-cores" (ASUS TUF Z790). In my first tests this fixes the issue. All cores run on 5300 MHz now. Multithreading is a lot more stable and performance more predictable.
I still have no idea what is causing this problem. It might be a Windows 10 update, or the software, or some driver update. It's still a mystery for me why only this software has problems, while others seem to work around it.
Thank you for the contributions in the comments. I might update to Windows 11 soon, as I understand Windows 11 handles multithreading a bit differently.
